# How to load script-related styles automatically?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, actions, wp-enqueue-style, scripts, automation

Scenario: It is common that a JS dependency is bundled with a style file to work properly (just think about your favorite slideshow jQuery plugin). AFAIK, in this situation, the script and style have to be included in separate `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` calls.

I am thinking about how to **automate this process**.

A solution I could come about is to declare the configuration in a .json file in which an entry looks like this:

```
"jquery-plugin": ["static/js/jquery-plugin.js", "1.0", ["jquery"], "jquery-plugin.css"]
```

(the configuration is `[file_path, version, js dependency, bundled css file]`).

When my plugin is loaded, the .json file is read, parsed and then the scripts and styles are registered. Also, information about whether a script has a bundled style file is kept in a global array, let's call it `$_scirpts_has_style`. With `$_scirpts_has_style`, the bundled style can get `wp_enqueue_style`'d automatically after the corresponding script is `wp_enqueue_script`'ed.

So, what I basically want is some signal which informs me that a script is enqueued, but I cannot find such signal (action/filter). `script_loader_src` is something very close but it is triggered when the script is getting printed, which is too late to enqueue a style file.

Is there any action/filter that does this? Or,

What's your solution to this problem?

Comment: There must be a specific condition to trigger the enqueuing of your script. Why don’t you use the same condition for your stylesheet?

Comment: @toscho You're right. But consider this: Once the user enqueues a script, all its dependencies are enqueued as well, which is done automatically and **silently** by WP. Auto-dependency resolving is a certain benefit to rely on, otherwise there's no meaning to use `wp_enqueue_script` system.

Comment: This is a very good question that I wondering about myself, what is the point of enqueuing script dependencies  automatically if they can't be coupled with their dependent styles? Its a big design hole imo. Has anyone had any luck solving it?

Comment: I think this is an excellent question, but for now, the only thing you could do is develop your own function which does this. WordPress is old and the purpose, in the beginning, was just blogging. I hope they will do something about there dependency issues.